# LT Spice Can't resolve .param vcc1=(vcc) problem

Tags: ltspice

I want to make a simulation in LTSpice bu using spice model of 74HC123.  I used below spice model.  But I take below errors and I can not make a simulation.

SPICE model:

```
* (DUAL) RETRIGGERABLE MONOSTABLE MULTIVIBRATOR
* Pulse Width Tw = 0.5 * R * C
* tpd R,A,B->Q     30n
* Tpulse 75n, C=0, Rext=5k
.SUBCKT 74HC123  A B CLR  CGND RC  Q QN  VCC VGND
.param egain=1/{vcc1}
.param td5=1e-9*(5)*4.0/({vcc1}-0.5)*{speed1}
.param td2=1e-9*(2)*4.0/({vcc1}-0.5)*{speed1}
*
XINA    A Ai  VCC VGND  74HC_IN_1  vcc2={vcc1}  speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
XINB    B Bi  VCC VGND  74HC_IN_1  vcc2={vcc1}  speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
XINCLR  CLR CLRi  VCC VGND  74HC_IN_1  vcc2={vcc1}  speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
XINRC1  RC RCi  VCC VGND  74HC_IN_0  vcc2={vcc1}  speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
*
* Model of a 74HC123 derived  from SGS-Thomson data sheet.
* Helmut Sennewald, 13.9.2002
A4 DHIGH 0 N014 0 N004 N006 N005 0 DFLOP   tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A3 0 N015 N016 N023 0  N014 0 0 OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A1 Ai 0 0 0 0          0 N015 0  SCHMITT  Vt=0.46 Vh=0.02  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A2 Bi 0 0 0 0          N016 0 0  SCHMITT  Vt=0.46 Vh=0.02  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A6 0 N008 0 N006 0     N007 0 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A5 0 N009 0 N007 0     N008 0 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A14 0 N003 0 N021 0    N004 0 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td2}
A13 0 N003 0 N005 0    0 N030 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A12 N005 0 0 0 0       N012 0 0  BUF  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A21 0 N010 0 N011 0    0 N009 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A22 0 N005 0 N007 0    N010 0 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A11 0 N013 0 N012 0    0 N003 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A7 0 N007 0 N018 0     QNi Qi 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A20 RCi 0 0 0 0        N011 0 0  SCHMITT  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}  Vt=0.44 Vh=0.2m
A10 RCi 0 0 0 0        0 N013 0  SCHMITT  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}  Vt=0.1 Vh=0.2m
A32 0 N006 0 N021 0    N022 0 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A31 0 N022 0 N023 0    N021 0 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td2}
A33 N021 0 0 0 0       N019 0 0  BUF  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A30 CLRi 0 0 0 0       N023 0 0  BUF  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A34 0 N007 0 N006 0    N020 0 0  AND  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A35 0 N020 0 N018 0    N017 0 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
A36 0 N017 0 N019 0    N018 0 0  OR  tripdt={tripdt1}  td={td5}
M10 RC N001 VGND VGND NMOS1
M30 RC N024 VCC VCC PMOS1
D1 RC VCC DIO1
D2 VGND RC DIO1
R10 N001 N002 100
R30 N024 N029 100
R3 CGND VGND 1
E4 RCi 0 RC VGND {egain}
E7 N029 VCC N018 0 {vcc1}
E8 N002 VGND N030 0 {vcc1}
V1 DHIGH 0 DC 1
.MODEL NMOS1 NMOS ( LEVEL=3  W=500e-6  L=1E-6  VTO=1
+ VMAX=1E6  RS=10  RD=10  CJ=0.002  MJ=0.4
+THETA=1E-6 ETA=0.01  KAPPA=2.2)
.MODEL PMOS1 PMOS ( LEVEL=3  W=500e-6  L=1E-6  VTO=-1
+ VMAX=1E6  RS=10  RD=10  CJ=0.002  MJ=0.4
+THETA=1E-6 ETA=0.01  KAPPA=2.2)
.MODEL DIO1 D (IS=10p RS=10 N=1.75 M=0.4 Cjo=6p TT=20n)
*
XOUT0  Qi  Q   VCC VGND  74HC_OUT_1X  vcc2={vcc1} speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
XOUT1  QNi QN  VCC VGND  74HC_OUT_1X  vcc2={vcc1} speed2={speed1}  tripdt2={tripdt1}
.ends
*
```

Errors:

```
WARNING: Can't resolve .param vdd1=vdd
WARNING: Can't resolve .param speed1=speed
WARNING: Can't resolve .param tripdt1=tripdt
```

How I can solve these problem?

Comment: This is not the LTspice / Pspice helpdesk. Read the rules to learn what kind of questions are welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

Get the newest libraries from the following Yahoo LTspice groups folder:

[LTspice 74HCxxx](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LTspice/files/%20Lib/Digital%2074HCxxx/)

The file there is called 74HC.LIB.

The .SUBCKT line should look like:

.SUBCKT 74HC123  A B CLR  CGND RC  Q QN  VCC VGND  vcc1={vcc} speed1={speed} tripdt1={tripdt}

You will also need all the symbols from the symbol library. That's in a file called 74HC.ZIP. Dump all those .ASC files into a convenient directory and make sure that you've gone into SETTINGS and set up the directory there (if you don't add it to the default symbol directory.)

If you place the symbol on the schematic and use ".include 74hc.lib" as a spice command on your schematic (use the 'S' keystroke to start that), and MAKE SURE you create a voltage source, grounded on the (-) side, and with a LABEL attached to its (+) side called "vcc" (and set to 5V), then things may work okay. To verify that your symbol is correct, right click the symbol and check that there is a non-empty SpiceLine there, with something like "VCC=5  SPEED=1.0  TRIPDT=1e-9" on it.